# Bat file MOVE fails due to other process handle

Tags: batch-file, filesystems, move

I have a bat file as part of larger maintenance system that runs on a nightly basis, performs a bit of housekeeping, SVN updating etc. Part of this involves moving/deleting files, however, occasionally this fails due to another process not releasing a handle on the files/dirs to be moved. Is there any way to force the BAT file to override any existing handles and continue with the MOVE? I can only think of a look up method using ProcessExplorer/Assassin - although I'm not sure that would even work. Alternatively a "sleep" and then reattempt if it failed the first time, although that would be a matter of luck than solving the underlying problem. Any ideas/suggestions much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy has a move function, and can wait on error

Comment: Thank you, it seems pretty promising so I will give it a go. The only thing is the syntax seems a bit different. e.g. I cannot seem to figure out the equivalent of COPY ./test1 ./test2; ROBOCOPY ./test1 ./test1 /MOVE seems to copy the contents of test1 into test2 without copying the parent test1. Trivial but it's frustrating me!

Comment: robocopy test1 test2 /move should move the contents inside test1 to inside test2.. if ou need a test1 directory in it, perhaps make the test1 directory and do it as robocopy test1 test2\test1 /move

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that I have done in similar situations:

- Before the `move` command, ensure that other script threads `CD` out of the target directory.
- Use [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) (from the [Resource Kits](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd)) with options like retry `/r:3` and wait `/w:5`.
- Script the first action as `COPY` so the script can continue working, then later in the script do the deletion at the old/unneeded location.
- As you've already mentioned, create a little retry loop using [IF ERRORLEVEL](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) commands to test the success of the `MOVE` command.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions, I will be attempting to use Robocopy with the R and W flags and see how it behaves. Cheers.

Comment: @qxn BTW, welcome to the StackOverflow community! You probably want to check off one of the answers so people can know that your question is answered...